# how to put in separator for textContent in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to convert an html table to a csv file using javascript. I tried to loop through the table rows & get the `textContent` from it and then saved it in an array & then convert that array to csv. But when I get `textContent` I do not have any separators between two words.

E.g.  if my html looks like this:

```
var ans = $("#my_table").find("table tr");

    <tr>
      <th>Test1</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Current </td>
      <td> Next </td>
    </tr>
```

when I loop through `<tr>` I get the following output:

```
Test1Test2
CurrentNext
```

However there is no space or any separator. How can I put in a seperator while looping, since I have to save that in csv format?

Looking for this output:

```
Test1,Test2
Current,Next
```

My js code:

```
for(var i=0; i<ans.length; i++){
    console.log(ans[i].textContent);
}
```

Comment: Why use the `.textContent` on the rows? Just iterate over the `.cells` of each row and get the `.textContent` per cell.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the code that retrieves the rows and then go through each row worth of cells.

```
var ans = $("#my_table").rows;
var tableText;

for (var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ans[i].cells.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            tableText += ans[i].cells[j].textContent;
        } else {
            tableText += "," + ans[i].cells[j].textContent;
        }
    }
    tableText += "\n";
}

console.log(tableText);
```

is one way that you could achieve those results, without having a trailing or preceding comma

Comment: @Malachi do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @bloomberg, yes, the one I have given

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a solution that doesn't depend on external libraries:

```
function tableToCSV(table) {
    var output = [], i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i += 1) {
        var temp = [];
        for (j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j += 1) {
            temp.push(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText);
        }
        output.push(temp.join(','));
    }
    return output.join('\n');
}

//to access your table use tableToCSV(document.getElementById('my_table'));
//or with jQuery tableToCSV($('#my_table')[0]);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/ejxqbyrm/

Comment: I have restriction so cannot use that sadly. :X

Comment: what are your restrictions?

Comment: need to use plain js or jquery. No other libraries.

Comment: vanilla JS is plain JS

Comment: so I don'nt need to include any library ?

Comment: Don't use `ans` at all, or if you do, just expect it to be a string that is the full CSV string

Comment: What does ans stand for, link please?

Comment: Don't forget to properly escape values for CSV otherwise this will fail when you have commas or quotes in the text of a table cell.

Comment: what do you mean by don't use ans at all @howderek ? var ans = $("#my_table").find("table");

Comment: Right, but you would replace that line with `var ans =  tableToCSV(document.getElementById('my_table'));`, I meant you won't use the code you have posted so far at all

Answer (score 1):

**There's no simple property for this, so you'll have to use a function or object of some kind**.

Here's my attempt [(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Spooniest/qra8tfj7/). It weighs in a little heavier than the other answers, but attempts to escape some of the text per the standard (or as close to a standard as CSV has):

```
function CSVRenderer() {}

CSVRenderer.prototype.escape = function (s) {
    // Escape double-quotes
    if (s.indexOf('"') !== -1) {
        s = s.replace(/"/g, '""');
    }
    // Surround text with containing, commas, or double-quotes
    if (
    s.indexOf(',') !== -1 || s.indexOf('\n') !== -1 || s.indexOf('"') !== -1) {
        s = '"' + s + '"';
    }
    return s;
};

CSVRenderer.prototype.renderCell = function (cell) {
    return this.escape(cell.textContent);
};

CSVRenderer.prototype.renderRow = function (row) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(
        row.cells,
        this.renderCell,
        this
    ).join(',');
};

CSVRenderer.prototype.render = function (table) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(
        table.rows,
        this.renderRow,
        this
    ).join('\n');
};
```

You could use it something like this:

```
var renderer = new CSVRenderer();
var csv = renderer.render(document.getElementById("my_table"));
```

If for whatever reason you have multiple tables per page, you can reuse `renderer` for each one.

The version above does some basic escaping per the CSV format, in that it will handle commas, text newlines, and quotes correctly. It doesn't handle uneven row lengths, though, and it might be useful to make it convert `<br>` tags into newlines. But for the use cases you've mentioned here, it ought to get the job done.

Answer (score -1):

Hope the following correction works:

```
var ans = $("#mytable").find("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
  var rows = ans[i].children;
  var rowText = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    rowText += rows[j].textContent;  //.trim() if you want
    if (j < (rows.length - 1)) {
        rowText += ",";
      }
    }
  console.log(rowText);
}
```

Comment: Nope if my input is This is test post43% The output is This,is,test,post,43% which is not correct. I want the output to be This is test post, 43%